# NodeJS multiple applications on same machine - about multithread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, multiple-instances

I am reading about nodejs being sigle threaded, but being able to use cluster module to fully use, with I assume a load balancer, cpu's capabilities.

I do not have much experience with nodejs, but I would like to understand what differences are there between using clusters, and launching multiple nodejs applications on the same machine using the same db and interacting each with the other using specific services if necessary, using different port, and handled by a master node instance that acts as load balancer.

Some instances could be left for cpu intensive use only (for theese I am oriented in using specific c++ compiled dedicated exes to run with node as children processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cluster` just spawns node child processes, each with a bidirectional IPC channel open to the parent process.

`cluster` also allows you to automatically load balance connections to a node server or you can explicitly pass TCP sockets and other special objects to the child process for them to handle instead of the parent. The `cluster` documentation shows examples of both of these features.

If you already have compiled executables that you want to execute per core and don't need to execute any JavaScript in the child processes, then you can probably just skip `cluster` and just spawn `require('os').cpus().length` instances of your compiled executable. Otherwise you could use `cluster` and then spawn the compiled executable from each of the node child processes if you need to do some preparation first or you are conditionally spawning the compiled executable.